# I can't get iOS device to remain awake

Tags: ios, iphone, sleep

I wrote this (what should be) crazy-simple app. (iOS 8.4.1, xcode 6.4, iPhone 6.) But it's not behaving the way I expected.

All it's supposed to do is display the current time, have the screen darken when face down on a surface, and never sleep.

I can supply actual code, and all sorts of investigative output, but here's the gist of it.

- It has two NSLabels that display the time.
- I created an NSTimer (1.0 secs) that calls a func that:  updates the content of the two NSLabels, and calls setNeedsDisplay for both of them.
- I set proximityMonitoringEnabled to true
- I set idleTimerDisabled to true

At first glance the app seems to function properly. The screen darkens when put face down, and lights up when lifted. The time updates just fine.

The problem is that the screen will occasionally fail to light back up when picked up. It seems like, in this case, the device has gone to sleep while it was face down. (I've checked the console logs, and it's not crashing.)

I can post the full source, and a lot of other debug data if it's useful, but my first question is, have I missed anything obvious here in trying to prevent the device from ever sleeping? Or, is there some known issue that requires special handling?

UPDATE, as a result another post on this site, about a seemingly related problem, I now don't simply set idleTimerDisabled to true, I first set it to false, then true. Also, I added another NSTimer which toggles idleTimerDisabled to false then true every 20 seconds. Neither of these seem to have solved the problem.

???

Comment: You see proximityMonitoringEnabled to true, but doesn't this require an element of user permission? If you don't ask for that permission (there's an sdk call for this), that command may be disregarded.

Comment: @sunny is that true? I've dug around, and I can't find any reference to such a permission. Can you give me a reference to a specific part of the sdk? Also, the proximityMonitoring part of my app seems to be working most of the time. It's just sometimes when it tries to come out of it, it fails.

Comment: It seems you are right. I am quite surprised there isn't an element of permission asking, but I can't find it either.